# Trying to generate Textbox fields from a Combo Box using Java

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, combobox

I'm fairly new to Java, and recently have been utilizing NetBeans to create GUIs. The issue I've been having is that I'm trying to fill information to text boxes based on a selected combo box selection. The information I want to fill fields is a lot more than I want in the combo box, so I was thinking of starting the combo box info with a number(the position in the arraylist used to generate the info) and then try to utilize said number in order to generate all the fields. There are two arrays that I utilize: the first is a  arraylist that stores all the information. The second is a  arraylist that is a combination of the position number (0+) the student ID, last and first name. The first character being the number, I thought to utilize it in order to find the information from the first array, as by design when one is generated, the other is. However, trying to utilize this button runs into a multitude of issues. I was looking for help either trying to get this to work or a better method of accomplishing this. Thanks, apologies if the concept used is strange, I am new to coding methodologies.

```
private void btnGenerateFieldsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                                  
        String x = String.valueOf(cbStudentPayrollList.getSelectedItem());
        char c = x.charAt(0);
        tbAptNo.setText(nameList.get(c).findApt());
        tbCity.setText(nameList.get(c).findCity());
        tbFirstName.setText(nameList.get(c).findFirstName());
        tbHourlyWage.setText(""+nameList.get(c).findHourlyWage());
        tbHoursWorked.setText(""+nameList.get(c).findHoursWorked());
        tbLastName.setText(nameList.get(c).findLastName());
        tbState.setText(nameList.get(c).findState());
        tbStreetAddress.setText(nameList.get(c).findAddress());
        tbStudentID.setText(""+nameList.get(c).findID());
        tbZipCode.setText(""+nameList.get(c).findZipCode());
    }
```

Stacktrace:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 49, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at StudentPayrollGUI.btnGenerateFieldsActionPerformed(StudentPayrollGUI.java:642)
    at StudentPayrollGUI.access$2400(StudentPayrollGUI.java:14)
    at StudentPayrollGUI$25.actionPerformed(StudentPayrollGUI.java:446)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Can you state your `multitude of issue`?

Comment: Don't post your stacktrace into comment section. YOu can edit the `Post` by using `edit` link under you posted question. make those edits there. ANd it looks like that you are trying to access element which is not present in your `ArrayList` throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're working in an object orientated language.  This means you should be thinking about how to encapsulate the information you need in self contained units of work (objects).

Instead of trying to link a value from a combo box to an array, you should actually add these objects directly to the combobox and take advantage of the rendering capabilities of the combobox to display the details of the object in the combobox the way you want it to be displayed.

Take a look at [How to use combo boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Providing a custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) in particular